# Masstransit error handling for batch consumer

Tags: masstransit

I've configured a consumer for receiving Batch of messages.  The consumer has also been configured for retry and re-delivery in case of any error happen. The batch consumer is working perfectly. But as I notice, in case of any error happen inside batch message, the whole batch becomes faulted.

As shown in the below example, let's assume that Message[2] becomes faulted, then it seems like that the whole batch is retrying/redelivering again before it's become faulted.

*My Query: Is there any way we can configure the consumer so that only faulted message(s) inside a batch try to redeliver or becomes faulted AND other messages inside batch will be resumed.*

```
public class MyConsumer : IConsumer<Batch<MyClass>>, IConsumer<Fault<MyClass>>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Batch<MyClass>> context)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < context.Message.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 2)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<MyClass>> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error in Context. Name :{context.Message.Message.Name}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When configured properly, the entire batch would be retried as a unit, which means you'd need to keep track of individual items another way. One approach is to have each item be a separate idempotent operation, but at that point the real question becomes "why are you using batch for discrete operations?"

If you're processing each message in a batch separately, just use a regular consumer and save yourself the complexity and hassle.

If you must use batch for whatever reason, consider catching the exceptions of individual messages and publishing some type of event signaling that the individual item failed.